# Using Instruments to memory profile an XPC service

Tags: objective-c, instruments, xpc

I'm curious if this is even possible. I'm suffering from a major memory leak or abandoned memory in an XPC service I've written, but I can't seem to track it down. I cannot figure out how to attach instruments to an XPC service.